# Connectivity graph proof

Tags: graph-theory

Let $G=(V,E)$ be an undirected graph, with
$\text{deg}(v)=p>1$
for all $v$ of $V$ and $|V|=2p+1$.
I want to show that exists in the graph an Euler circle. I was able to prove that the graph is even, but I can't prove the graph is connected.
Thanks for the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose that $G$ is not connected. Let $G_1,..., G_k$, $k\geq 2$, be the connected components of $G$.

Since $\sum_{i=1}^k|V(G_i)|=|V(G)|=2p+1$ and $k\geq 2$, there exists $i$ such that $|V(G_i)|\leq p$. For each vertex $v$ in $G_i$, its degree must satisfy
$\deg(v)\leq |V(G_i)|-1=p-1$ (since it can only be adjacent to
the vertices in $G_i$), which contradicts to the assumption that $\deg(v)=p$ for all vertices $v$ in $G$.

Comment: Thanks for the response,Just to be sure I understood you,v(G I)<= p Because of division 2p+1/k? Sorry for the signs, I'm writing from the iPad

Comment: @complex_stock Yes, right. Exactly. The minimum of $|V(G_i)|$ satisfies $|V(G_i)|\leq (2p+1)/k\leq (2p+1)/2\leq p+\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: And it's not a problem to say p+1/2 ? Becaus Vertex can only be an integer

Comment: Yes. That's right.